# problem rendering items with props.match.params.id

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a simple query string matches to show the appropriate item.
here is the component which will render further info on a listed item:

```
const Product = (props) => {
console.log(props.match.params.id)
console.log(data.products)
  const product = data.products.find((x) => x.id === props.match.params.id);
    if (!product) {
      return <div>product not found!</div>;
    }
```

while both of thoese consule logs give me what i want the product does not seem to be found. here is my product list:

```
const data={
  products:[
    {
      id:1,
      brand:'Nappies',
      price:1200
    },
    {
      id:2,
      brand:'Knitted Goods',
      price:1400
    },
    {
      id:3,
      brand:'Baked Treats',
      price:1100
    },
    {
      id:4,
      brand:'Clothes',
      price:1100
    }
  ]
}
```

and i am matching the querys with this ...

```
<Link to={`/product/${product.id}`}><button className="card bg-gray-700 hover:bg-red-600 transition text-white w-full h-1/6 absolute bottom-0">See More</button></Link>
```

the above button is the button a user clicks to see more on that item (price, name, stock, etc)

when clicking that link it takes me to the appropriate page url. (http://localhost:3000/product/2 )but its giving me the "no item found visually on the page"

this is how my app.js is set up... fairly simply:

```
      <Nav />
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/'>
    <Homepage />
    </Route>
<Route path='/product/:id' component={Product}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

it seems to be like the find method isn't working? such a bizarre problem.  am i missing something really obvious? been coding about a year and still find myself stumped on simple react stuff lately :/ so discouraging.

its not rendering any of my info after that in the individial product component
shown down below:

```
    <li>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div>{product.name}</div>
                    <div className="price">{product.price}</div>
                  </div>
                </li>
```

essentially i want the above code rendered after clicking one of the listed items. its saying "cannot get id of undefined".... seems to be something with me find method but even then i still can't figure out what could be wrong?!?

Comment: Can you give the exception stack trace printed on console which is your `cannot get id of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

`propps.match.params.id` seems to be a `string`

but, when your looks for a particular product, you use strict match

```
const product = data.products.find((x) => x.id === props.match.params.id);
```

your id is number, `'2' === 2` is false

So, try

```
const product = data.products.find((x) => x.id === Number(props.match.params.id));
```

Comment: omggg that was the problem thank you!!!!! i figured that was the problem because when i tried == earlier it was giving me a match but not in the way i wanted... thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do use useParams hook to retrieve id as

```
const Product = (props) => {    
      let { id } = useParams();
      return (
         <div>
              <h3>ID: {id}</h3>
         </div>
      );
}
```

For further details check here https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params